# Parse json and show with tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm new to Swift, and not good at manipulating json and hash.

Here's my JSON [Array of Users]

```
[
{"name": "mary", "age": 24, "detail": "i love ..."},
{"name": "mark", "age": 28, "detail": "i love ..."}
]
```

I want to show each user's name first and then their `age`

And If you click there name or age, it will show the `detail`

I only know how to iterate a array and puts the value on the cell.

Like this way, but now knowing how to display tablecells with a dictionary

`cell.textLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.row]`

How could I know which `key` should I use in each loop ?

`func tableView(invoice: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {`

How could I know this time, I should use the `name` , and next time I should use `age` to show my cell?

[image]

Comment: Maybe `cell.textLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.row]["name"];`?

Comment: But how about show the `age` ? Maybe there are many users. The logic seems so complicated

Comment: then you use `"age"` instead of `"name"`. Is that really that complicated?

Comment: make an array of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your original JSON is an array, you can parse the JSON elements in a dictionary and then use it in your cell.

```
func parseJSONArray(jsonData: NSData) -> Array<NSDictionary>{
    var error: NSError?
    var usersDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as Array<NSDictionary>
    return usersDictionary
}
```

Then you can use this usersDictionary to get your users info:

```
cell.textlabel.text = usersDictionary[indexPath.row].valueForKey("name")
```

For the logic of key decision, try something like below:

```
var index = indexPath.row/2;
var key = indexPath.row%2;

if (key == 0) { //show the name cell
    cell.textlabel.text = usersDictionary[index].valueForKey("name")
} else { //show the age cell
    cell.textlabel.text = "Age " + usersDictionary[index].valueForKey("age")
}
```

Similar logic for cell font style and color can be used by you. Its not very complex. Just make sure to have number of rows as twice the json array size (1 cell for each key) and also proper logic for cell selected method.

Comment: Hi How to decide which key to use in each loop

Comment: Well, that depends on your table design. If the design is like you have given in the screenshot then let me know?

Answer (score 0):

try this code, because name is show in even cell, age show in odd

```
var index = indexPath.row/2;
var isAgeCell = indexPath.row%2
if (isAgeCell == 0) {
    cell.textLabel.text = self.items[index]["name"]
}
else {
    cell.textLabel.text = self.items[index]["age"]
}
```

Comment: Hi, Is there more elegant way? like show 2 cells at a time, one for 'name' and one for 'age'